# Flipping multiple divs by clicking different buttons using CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm really new to Javascript. I've been playing around a bit, and had managed to get multiple div's on a page to flip individually, using tutorials and some other help. Now, I want to see if I can flip those same div's using a button or a hyperlink instead.

I thought it would be as simple as moving the class that controls the flip to the button, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I've read that I need to adjust my Javascript to work from a passed id.

Problem is, I don't know how to do this. I've tried passing the button id through to my Javascript function on click (like so: `<button class="flip-it" onClick="flipThis(card-1)">Click Me</button>`), but that doesn't work. I'm probably way off base here.

My fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j0sfbd60/). I've left the third div as I had it before, working, just to show you what I've started from.

Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<p>some content above the flip card</p>

<h1>The CSS flip card:</h1> 
<div class="large_box_main">
    <div>
        <div class="sm_box" id="card-1">
            <div class="flipcard">
                <div class="flipcard-front">
                    <div class="sm_img_box">
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.catchat.org/images/ferals_block_2009.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="sm_info_box">
                         <h2>Ginger</h2> 
                         <h3>Cat 1</h3> 
                         <h4>Male</h4> 
                        <p class="info">Front</p>
                        <button class="flip-it" onClick="flipThis(card-1)">Click Me</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flipcard-back">
                    <div class="sm_info_box">
                         <h2>Ginger</h2> 
                         <h3>Cat 1</h3> 
                         <h4>Male</h4> 
                        <p class="info">Back</p>
                        <button class="flip-it" onClick="flipThis(card-1)">Click Me</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="sm_box" id="card-2">
                <div class="flipcard">
                    <div class="flipcard-front">
                        <div class="sm_img_box">
                            <img class="image" src="http://www.petrescue.org.nz/files/animal/attachment/93/small_cats.h5.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="sm_info_box">
                             <h2>Tabby</h2> 
                             <h3>Cat 2</h3> 
                             <h4>Female</h4> 
                            <p class="info">Front</p>
                            <button class="flip-it" onClick="flipThis(card-2)">Click Me</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flipcard-back">
                        <div class="sm_info_box">
                             <h2>Tabby</h2> 
                             <h3>Cat 2</h3> 
                             <h4>Female</h4> 
                            <p class="info">Back</p>
                            <button class="flip-it" onClick="flipThis(card-2)">Click Me</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sm_box flip-it">
                <div class="flipcard">
                    <div class="flipcard-front">
                        <div class="sm_img_box">
                            <img class="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/0f/4a/56/0f4a5681046ad10f36098451bf2128d2.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="sm_info_box">
                             <h2>Siamese</h2> 
                             <h3>Cat 3</h3> 
                             <h4>Male</h4> 
                            <p class="info">Front</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flipcard-back">
                        <div class="sm_info_box">
                             <h2>Siamese</h2> 
                             <h3>Cat 3</h3> 
                             <h4>Male</h4> 
                            <p class="info">Back</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.large_box_main {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px 0px 10px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
.sm_box {
    width:180px;
    /* The width of this element */
    margin:10px 15px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #e3d9ec;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float:left;
}
.sm_box:hover {
    border: 1px solid #9975B9;
}
.sm_img_box {
    width:165px;
    margin:6px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
.sm_info_box {
    width:165px;
    margin:8px;
    background-color:#e3d9ec;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
img.image {
    display:block;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.flipcard {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 0px;
    /* Flip card styles: WebKit, FF, Opera */
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: min-height 1s ease-out 0s, -webkit-transform 1s ease-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: min-height 1s ease-out 0s, -moz-transform 1s ease-out 0.5s;
    -o-transition: min-height 1s ease-out 0s, -o-transform 1s ease-out 0.5s;
    /* only height adjustment for IE here */
    -ms-transition: min-height 1s ease-out 0s;
}
/* The class that flips the card: WebKit, FF, Opera */
 .flipcard.card-flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipcard .flipcard-front, .flipcard .flipcard-back, .front, .back {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* backface: all browsers */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    /* Flip card styles: IE 10,11 */
    -ms-perspective: 800px;
    -ms-transform-style: flat;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease-out 0.5s;
}
.flipcard .flipcard-front, .front, .back {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flipcard .flipcard-back {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    /*  webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54371,
          You need this fix if you have any input tags on your back face */
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
}
/* The 2 classes that flip the faces instead of the card: IE 10,11 */
 .flipcard .flipcard-front.ms-front-flipped {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipcard .flipcard-back.ms-back-flipped {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.info {
    text-align:justify;
    padding:0px 5px;
    line-height:initial;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function flipThis() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var card = $this.find('.flipcard');
    var front = $this.find('.flipcard-front');
    var back = $this.find('.flipcard-back');
    var tallerHight = Math.max(front.height(), back.height()) + 'px';
    var visible = front.hasClass('ms-front-flipped') ? back : front;
    var invisible = front.hasClass('ms-front-flipped') ? front : back;
    var hasTransitioned = false;
    var onTransitionEnded = function () {
        hasTransitioned = true;
        card.css({
            'min-height': '0px'
        });
        visible.css({
            display: 'none',
        });
        // setting focus is important for keyboard users who might otherwise
        // interact with the back of the card once it is flipped.
        invisible.css({
            position: 'relative',
            display: 'inline-block',
        }).find('button:first-child,a:first-child').focus();
    }

    // this is bootstrap support, but you can listen to the browser-specific
    // events directly as well
    card.one($.support.transition.end, onTransitionEnded);

    // for browsers that do not support transitions, like IE9
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!hasTransitioned) {
            onTransitionEnded.apply();
        }
    }, 2000);

    invisible.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'inline-block'
    });

    card.css('min-height', tallerHight);
    // the IE way: flip each face of the card
    front.toggleClass('ms-front-flipped');
    back.toggleClass('ms-back-flipped');
    // the webkit/FF way: flip the card
    card.toggleClass('card-flipped');
}

$('button.flip-it').click(flipThis);
$('div.flip-it').click(flipThis);
```

Cheers!
(Edited to show code)

Comment: Please post the code on stack overflow, not just a link to the fiddle.

Comment: So as I saw your code, you need to modify the function flipThis as it is always taking the whole div as element in which it looks for the child elements. You need to check what was clicked, if that was button, you have to set $this to $(this).parent().parent(); and that's it. or $(this).closest('.sm_box');

Comment: if possible you can  use the link http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: Did the answer not help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a modified function flipThis and removed the onclick actions from your html. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0sfbd60/3/)

As I wrote in the comment, you have to recognize where you are currently in DOM. The code is self explanatory I suppose. And I also added a parameter to the flipThis function, so we know more precisely what we are working with. (not really needed, we could still work with $(this) but this is my way of doing things.

```
if($(e.currentTarget).prop('tagName')=="BUTTON")
    $this = $(this).closest('.sm_box');
else
    $this = $(this);
```

Comment: Thanks, @jPO, that definitely helped. The whole `$this` code in Javascript really confuses me. I'm going to have to read up on it further.